# Remove code from Wordpress CMS Script

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

edited question... I feel people may be misunderstanding my question, so i apologise for any ambiguity

[image]

As you can see from the above picture, I have text in the top left hand corner of the CMS.

This text is the same on every page and I feel it is having a negative effect on the running of the CMS.

I have no clue how it got there and as a result have no clue how to get rid of it

I have a feeling I have managed to insert code as text in a php script but am unsure which one as I only eve open scripts related to my child theme.

Does anyone have any idea which scripts may link directly to the CMS and cause the above?

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP open and close tag when you write PHP script. otherwise it consider as HTML.

```
<?php add_filter( 'pwb-single-product-brands', _'return_false'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ie8 wp-toolbar"  lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 8) ]><!-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wp-toolbar"  lang="en-US">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

Comment: just to add a little explanation for the OP: without the php tags `<?php` and `?>`, your code was treated as html, then diplayed to screen

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  My issue is... I do not want that there, I want to remove it completely. but i cannot find what PHP script it is in. I am keen to find out if anyone knows which script I should check to potentially find it.... I have only ever entered it into functions.php. I found it did not work so removed it. I have no idea how it ended up there

Comment: i think you are using a plugin "Perfect WooCommerce Brands" if you want to remove this code should uninstall the plugin.

Comment: Hi Sunil, this is the plug in that I am using.  As a result, the brand shows on the product page where the category and SKU would show... I wanted to remove the brand so tried using that code in function.php... the line did now show prior to putting that it. I have deleted it from functions.php but it still shows here. I am unsure if deleting plugin would help?

Comment: do not change your function.php, go to plugin js and try to change there. will helps to hide the brand.

Comment: brilliant, ill give that a shot. have you any idea how to remove the text from my CMS as in the above picture?  it seems to be causing problems when trying to upload CSVs to the database

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks, my own stupidity. I have solved the problem using a script search in VS Code.

thank you all for your input